# Drop down changes automatically ( vise versa would be best )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the 3rd field automatically depending on first two field. ( it would be best if I change 3rd field and then first 2 fields changes also  )

I need a Jquery solution. Anyone can help me please?

```html
<select id="First">
  <option val="car">car</option>
  <option val="phone">phone</option>
</select>

<select id="Second">
  <option val="car">car</option>
  <option val="phone">phone</option>
  <option val="boll">boll</option>
</select>
<hr>
<select id="ChangeItAutomatically">
  <option val="carcar">car car</option>
  <option val="carphone">car phone</option>
  <option val="carboll">car boll</option>
  <option val="phonecar">phone car</option>
  <option val="phonephone">phone phone</option>
  <option val="phonecarboll">phone boll</option>
</select>
```

Comment: a) Your question makes little to no sense b) where is your code and what have you tried?

Comment: Please add your code to the question itself.  Please take a moment and read [Help Center > Asking > How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: To get you started: [jQuery's Learning Center](http://learn.jquery.com/), [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/), [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/), and [`+` for concatenation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Addition). Also, tip for "*it would be best [..]*:" You'll need to establish a way to predictably separate, for example, `carphone` into words – noting that JavaScript doesn't understand they're words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // on change for the 3rd select
  $("#ChangeItAutomatically").on("change", function() {
    // get the value and split on space
    var value = $(this).val().split(" ");
    
    // select the other two selects based on the values
    $("#First").val(value[0]);
    $("#Second").val(value[1]);
  });

  // on change for the first two selects
  $("#First, #Second").on("change", function() {
    // set the value of the 3rd select based on the combination of values of the first two
    $("#ChangeItAutomatically").val($("#First").val() + " " + $("#Second").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="First">
  <option val="car">car</option>
  <option val="phone">phone</option>
</select>

<select id="Second">
  <option val="car">car</option>
  <option val="phone">phone</option>
  <option val="boll">boll</option>
</select>
<hr>
<select id="ChangeItAutomatically">
  <option val="car car">car car</option>
  <option val="car phone">car phone</option>
  <option val="car boll">car boll</option>
  <option val="phone car">phone car</option>
  <option val="phone phone">phone phone</option>
  <option val="phone boll">phone boll</option>
</select>
```